# Can I Paginate Post after every 25 <li> tag?

Tags: posts, loop, pagination, tags

I want to create new post page after every 25 (li /li) tags. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you please add a example, the question is not clear

Comment: There is a quote site, and there are hundreds of quotes on one page sometimes. I want to split every 25 quote by 1 page.

Comment: Where did you get your  `<li></li>`? Any code or explanation?

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to split one posts into a few pages, you could use a plugin such as [custom next page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-nextpage/). Or with the tag  without a plugin.

If you mean you want 25 posts in page with posts list (archive page) , you could set [Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination), You could see example in cods.

Or through admin dashboard ui settings->Reading->Blog pages show at most and set number of posts you eant to be displayed in page.

Comment: I'm talking about inpost pagination. I need to split 25 quotes to 1 page.

Comment: Each quote is a post? Could you put a link to the site?

Comment: Guzelmesaj.com each quote is in ki tag. O need to insert <!--newpage--> after every 25 li /li tag

Comment: @BatıkanGençACAT you could add the <!--newpage--> after saving post with hooking into "save post" and looping over the li tags with simple-php-dom

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is quite good at paginating native data structures, such as posts and terms (until you get up to hundreds of thousands of them, but that's another story).

WordPress is quite bad at paginating anything custom at all. Most of the processing needs to be rebuilt, starting with custom Rewrite rules, which is confidently *the worst* API in core.

So the main question for custom pagination is — is it reasonable to convert to a native data type, such as custom post type or taxonomy?

If the answer is yes then that's the course of action. Otherwise it might be easier to bite the bullet and do one–off with in–post pagination and call it good enough.